# CHKDSK on Windows 7 taking too long

Tags: windows-7

It is now 3 days since I started CHKDSK and is still on 51%.  The current status is: 2CHKDSK is verifying Security descriptors (Stage 3 of 3).  Repairing the security file record segment.  51 per cent complete (599226 of 132864 file SDS/SI processed).  This final 3rd stage is taking awfully long.  At the current rate it is going to take just undera year to finish!!  I have read that once CHKDSK is started that it should not be stopped.  But as you will appreciate a year is a long time to wait.  Any advice would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Just my two cents: The HDD is dying? :) (Try checking it with SMART, maybe with using an Ubuntu Live disc. Use "badblocks" to check your HDD surface. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FaultyHardware)

Comment: You could have slow CPU/RAM? How old is your HDD? Brand? Speed (rpm)?

Comment: There are many parameters for starting a chkdsk, some of them seem to go over every friggen cluster,  which on >1T disks can take forever. What is the exact set of parameters you used for starting it? Or what is the GUI selection item used for starting it?

Comment: How big is this harddrive?  2TB harddrives can take over two days, especially a full chkdsk.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your computer, give it a break for a few hours and then run chkdsk again.  It just got stuck.

Comment: I agree within the context that the user already knows that "it is not supposed to be stopped".  I have seen it stick up like this before. After a reboot, it was able to complete the same, without problems for me.

Comment: "give it a break for a few hours"?

Comment: Give it a break, goes with "run a thermal probe on the disk"?  It would depend on the cooling of the system. Non-stop work for even a "green drive" , in a poor air movement location, and the disk can be warmer than normal operations.